# If I move a form with VSTA code-behind into Visual Studio, will end users require the VSTO runtime?

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, vsto, infopath, vsta

I have an existing InfoPath 2007 form that has some code-behind developed with VSTA. It has been deployed to SharePoint as an administrator-approved form but is *not* browser based - the InfoPath client opens when users fill in a new form.

I'd now like to follow [How to: Migrate a Project Created in Visual Studio Tools for Applications to Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa947042(office.11).aspx) and move this code into Visual Studio so it's easier to manage and integrated with source control.

Will migrating the form to Visual Studio introduce a dependency on the VSTO runtime so that end users will need to have it deployed to their machines for the form to run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving it from InfoPath 2007 to Visual Studio will not introduce any new *runtime* dependencies. I have done this in the past. All you're doing is wrapping it up in a nice csproj/vbproj and solution.